# ListView doesn't fill up screen

Tags: android, listview, widget, textview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview that I have made and while there is not enough items to fill up the entire screen. I have set my background color to something other than the default so of course my listview looks really bad right now. Is there a way I can get to fill the rest of the screen?

**settings_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_bkg"
>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/selection"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:background="@color/gray_bkg"
    />

    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:background="@color/gray_bkg"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
package shc_BalloonSat.namespace;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SettingsActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private String[] list = {"Get Last 5 Packets", "Get Last 10 Packets", "Get Last 20 Packets",
            "Change View"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.settings_list, R.id.selection , list);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
}
```

Also why do I need the listview widget when the adapter only wants me to pass it the id of the textview?

UPDATE:

I updated my XML code above. Even though I added the background color to the LinearLayout the background below my listview is still the default black.

Comment: If you're after full screen background color, easiest change would be to move background color setting to outmost LinearLayout.

Comment: "Also why do I need the listview widget when the adapter only wants me to pass it the id of the textview?" If you remove the ListView, where will the adapter display its TextViews? The ListView is mandatory, it provides order and function (like the `onListItemClick()` method.)

Comment: @Sam but still how does it even know it's there when I'm not passing it to the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

> I have set my background color to something other than the default

The best way to apply styles characteristics, like colors, is with [Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). A Theme can set the background color of everything in one place using a few lines of code.

> I updated my XML code above. Even though I added the background color to the LinearLayout the background below my listview is still the default black.

The ListView rows don't receive characteristics, like background, from the ListView element. The rows receive their characteristics from your row layout defined here:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.settings_list, R.id.selection , list);
```

The background in `settings_list.xml` needs to be transparent or set to the same color as everything else.

---

Moved up from comments:

> "Also why do I need the listview widget when the adapter only wants me to pass it the id of the textview?"

If you remove the ListView, where will the adapter display its TextViews? The ListView is mandatory, it provides order and function (like the onListItemClick() method.)

> but still how does it even know it's there when I'm not passing it to the adapter?

You are using a ListActivity. One requirement of a ListActivity is to have a ListView in your layout with the id `android:id/list`. The ListActivity automatically uses this ListView, setting many of the features for you, and understand that you *are* passing the ArrayAdapter to your ListView when you call:

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope that helps!